# Flutter passing list of strings in CupertinoPicker widget using loops

Tags: flutter, dart

I was trying to pass a list inside CupertinoPicker using loops  but I couldn't figure it

[this image contains the function I was trying to build](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0zuI.png)

```
 const List<String> currenciesList = [
          'AUD',
          'BRL',
          'CAD',
          'CNY',
          'EUR',
          'GBP',
          'HKD',
          'IDR',
          'ILS',
          'INR',
          'JPY',
          'MXN',
          'NOK',
        ];        

    Container(
            height: 150.0,
            alignment: Alignment.center,
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
            color: Colors.lightBlue,
            child:CupertinoPicker(
                backgroundColor: Colors.lightBlue,
                itemExtent: 32.0,
                onSelectedItemChanged: (selectedIndex){
                  print(selectedIndex);
                }, children:[
              Text('USD',style: whiteColor ),
              Text('EUR' , style: whiteColor),
              Text('GDP', style:whiteColor),
            ]
            ),
          ),
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of [Dart 2.3](https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#spread-operator) you can use `Collection For`:

```
CupertinoPicker(
children:[
          for (String name in currenciesList) Text( name ,style: whiteColor ), 
        ]
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should create a Func to get all value in your list.

```
List<Widget> getPickerItems() {
    List<Text> itemsCurrency = [];
    for (var currency in currenciesList) {      
      itemsCurrency.add(Text(currency));
    }
    return itemsCurrency;
  }
```

and add it in to children of CupertinoPicker:

```
CupertinoPicker(             
              children: getPickerItems(),
)
```